# Google Analytics Event Tracking "labels" not recorded

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, label, tracking

I'm using Google Analytics event tracking with the new asynchronous code. I have specified a set a categories and actions, and they show up just fine in my analytics profile. However, I know that I have pushed elements to the gaq array which includes labels as well, but they never show up in my analytics profile, even though I wait 24/48/72 hours. My code looks like this, is placed in a seperate file (GA.js) and is referenced from default.aspx (only page in the site, all subsequent page requests are through AJAX):

```
function GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent(Category, Action, Label) {
    //alert(Category + "|" + Action + "|" + Label);
    if (Label) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', Category, Action, Label]);
    }
    else {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', Category, Action]);
    }
} 

function GoogleAnalyticsTrackPage() {
    //alert('track page');
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
}

/* Code below is executed when default.aspx is loaded, and only then */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20332645-1']);
GoogleAnalyticsTrackPage();
GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent(MobileRequestType_MobileWeb, "Accessed Login Area");

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here's a different call that includes the label parameter:

```
GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent(CurrentMobileRequestType, '" + pAction + "','Exception Message Displayed');"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code you're showing, you never actually pass a `label` parameter to the `GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent()` function. So, the `if(Label)` conditional returns false, and the `else` block executes, and sends a tracking event without the `Label`. In order to have a label, you'll need to pass a third parameter in that function.

Comment: That's true, from what I've shown I never pass a label. Below is an example of where I do it. When I enable the alert-lines in the function I provided above, the correct and expected values are received by the GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent function.

GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent(CurrentMobileRequestType, '" + pAction + "','Exception Message Displayed');"

Comment: @Rene Vutborg you're going to need to provide more information. What you've shown here makes it seem like this data should be tracking just fine.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't really make a difference. The only thing I can think of would provide value is the fact that "mis-behaviour" is occuring in a development environment. With this I mean that all calls to GoogleAnalyticsTrackEvent originate from http://localhost:81, and not the web site URL I have specified in my google analytics settings. Perhaps, when this is the case, labels does not work, even though categories and actions works just fine...

Comment: That is not likely to be the case. The domain you specify in your account actually affects very little, and almost nothing in terms of actual traffic.